# Mongoose getters not working on arrays

Tags: node.js, mongoose, getter

I am trying to get some encryption working on a mongodb collection through a Node.js api.  The solution i have come across seems to work on the most part with the exception of decrypting any data that is sat within an array / nested document.

Code so far..

memberModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var crypto = require('crypto');
var connection = mongoose.connection;

var memberSchema = new Schema({
        title: {type: String, trim: true},
        firstname: {type: String, trim: true, get: decrypt, set: encrypt},
        lastname: {type: String, trim: true},
        address: [{
            addressRef: {type: String, trim: true},
            address1: {type: String, trim: true, get: decrypt, set: encrypt},
            postcode: {type: String, trim: true}
        }],
        ...
    }    , { collection: 'memberStage'});

memberSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true });
memberSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true });

function encrypt(text){
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'test');
    var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex');
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return crypted;
};

function decrypt(text){
    if (text === null || typeof text === 'undefined') { return text;};
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', 'test');
    var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8');
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return dec;
};

module.exports = connection.model('memberStage', memberSchema);
```

member.js

```
member.find(query, function(err, member){
    res.status(200).json({
        meta : { success: true, message: 'Member Data'},
        data : member
    });
});
```

In the database both the firstname and address.address1 fields are encrypted as expected however the json returned from the member.find call returns the decrypted firstname but the address1 field is still encrypted.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "success": true,
        "message": "Member Data"
    },
    "data": [
    {
        "_id": "5b1072549378101218c7039c",
        "title": "Mr",
        "firstname": "Test",
        "lastname": "Record",
        "address": [
            {
                "addressRef": "Home",
                "address1": "cfefdf8c4813fac7bcc34d919aa81483",
                "postcode": "PST CDE",
            }
        ]
    }],
    ...
}
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address should be defined as a schema and apply the same `toObject` and `toJSON` treatments for its getters.

```
var addressSchema = new Schema({
    addressRef: {type: String, trim: true},
    address1: {type: String, trim: true, get: decrypt, set: encrypt},
    postcode: {type: String, trim: true}
})

var memberSchema = new Schema({
        title: {type: String, trim: true},
        firstname: {type: String, trim: true, get: decrypt, set: encrypt},
        lastname: {type: String, trim: true},
        address: [addressSchema],
    }    , { collection: 'memberStage'});

addressSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true });
addressSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true });

memberSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true });
memberSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true });
```